# Сравнительный оборот, нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, сравнительный-оборот

*С глубокой древности отношение к искусству сформировалось **не как к развлечению**, а как к могучей силе, способной передать образ времени.*

Нужна ли запятая перед "не как к развлечению"?

Answer (score 5):

С глубокой древности отношение к искусству сформировалось не как к развлечению, а как к могучей силе, способной передать образ времени.

Запятая не нужна, здесь противопоставление НЕ...А, отнесенное к обстоятельственным оборотам с союзом КАК (они являются однородными).

Другой вариант: С глубокой древности  искусство воспринималось не как  развлечение, а как могучая сила, способная передать образ времени.

Answer (score 3):

> Нужна ли запятая перед *"не как к развлечению"*?

Не нужна.

См. [**ПАС:**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125)

> **§ 90.** Обороты со сравнительными союзами (частицами) ***как***, словно, будто, точно, как будто, что не выделяются запятыми в
>   следующих случаях:
>
> <…>
>
> д) если сравнительному обороту предшествует отрицание ***не*** или
>   частицы *совсем, совершенно, почти, вроде, точь-в-точь, именно,
>   просто* и др.: *Да он всё делает **не как** люди* (М. Г.); *Стало
>   светло почти как днем; Он выглядел совершенно (совсем) как ребенок.*

Обратите внимание на неправильный выбор глагола. У вас так:

> *С глубокой древности отношение к искусству **сформировалось**...*

Правильно так:

*С глубокой древности отношение к искусству **формировалось**...*

Answer (score 1):

Несколько дополнений к уже сказанному в ответах других участников.

- Порядок слов в этом предложении странный, я бы даже сказал неприемлемый. Оборот "не как к развлечению, а как к могучей силе, способной передать образ времени" относится к словам "отношение к искусству", а стоит после "сформировалось".
- Корректный выбор глагола: или "с глубокой древности формировалось", или "в глубокой древности сформировалось".

Исправленный вариант:

**С глубокой древности формировалось отношение к искусству не как к развлечению, а как к могучей силе, способной передать образ времени.**